# Partial Indexing Error in Python Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have created a **Hierarchical indexed** Series and I wanted to partially index some values of the Series. But When I changed the alphabetic order of the Series. The partially indexing is not working. Can anybody explain why is this happening? 
with Some better and logical explanation.

```
sr = Series(np.arange(11),index=[['a','b','b','c','d','d','e','e','f','f','f'],[1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,3]])
print (sr['a':'c'])
```

[image: Output]

This gives the resultant output but when I change the alphabetic order of the indexes, the partial indexing gives an error.

```
hs = Series(np.arange(10),index=[['a','a','b','b','c','c','d','e','e','a'],[1,0,2,1,0,1,1,3,2,3]])
print(hs['a':'c'])
```

> pandas.errors.UnsortedIndexError: 'Key length (1) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (0)'

[image]

Comment: In your case `hs.sort_index(level=0)['a':'c']`